# Cannot load stylesheets node

Tags: node.js, express

I have created basic node/express server

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var path    = require('path')
var port    = 8080;

app.use("/styles",  express.static('../public/styles'));

app.get('/' , function( req , res ){
    console.log(__dirname)
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'../public/html/index.html'))
})
app.listen(port)
```

structure of project is simple

```
app
  public
     html
       index.html
     styles
     javascripts
  routes
     server.js
```

html file looks very simple

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/index.css">
    <title> Hello world!</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

yet it still complains

> GET http://localhost:8080/index.css 404 (Not Found)

Yet my paths should be correct , i looked up this problem and every answer is about using

```
app.use("/styles",  express.static('../public/styles'));
```

so browser know how to redirect when looking for a stylesheets. Which does not work for me.

Could anybody help with this common problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you try removing the `..` in your link path?  Just use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/index.css">`

Comment: @DaveV tried it , it isnt working

Comment: Did it change the path that it was attempting to GET the css file from?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/styles/index.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) is erroe message now

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what your project structure is. It's more common to have `app.js` in your project directory contain the basic express server and if you have complicated routing, do that in `routes/server.js`

So you could change your project structure:

```
app.js (main file)
public
  index.html        
  styles
    index.css
  javascripts
routes
  server.js --not needed?
```

If that's the case, change app.js to:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var port    = 8080;

//use static folder public to serve everything up
app.use(express.static('./public/'));

app.listen(port)
```

In `index.html`, to include `index.css`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/index.css" >
```